# Unable to complete correct output for loop and exit strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

```
`entryprice = close
// Initialize profit target
 profit_target = entryprice

// Calculate stop loss and take profit levels
long_stop_loss = entryprice -1
long_take_profit = entryprice * 1.6  
// Calculate stop loss and take profit levels
short_stop_loss = entryprice + .02
short_take_profit = entryprice - 1 

shortcondition = ta.crossunder(src,lower+slope_pl*length)   
if shortcondition
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, comment = "Entered Short 1")
    num_bars = 5
    bar_count = 0
    while bar_count < num_bars
        // Display ID of the latest open position
        if close < entryprice +.03
            //strategy.exit("Exit on .03% loss", "Short", loss=short_stop_loss)
            break
        else if close >= entryprice -1
            strategy.exit("Exit - Profit", "buy", profit = short_take_profit)
            break
        else 
            bar_count += 1
            strategy.close("closed")`
        

`if shortcondition
     strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, comment = "Entered Short 1")
     strategy.exit("Exit on .03% loss", "Short", loss=short_stop_loss)
 if shortcondition
     strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, comment = "Entered Short 1")
     strategy.exit("Exit - Profit", "buy", profit = short_take_profit)`
```

So based on this while loop I understand I set it to 5 bars count I believe. Even if this is wrong I have tried this method as well. while true. Im honestly thinking of just writing another method to where it just does both like this but it seems like I wont get the data I want you know.

Currently I am having a problem where I write a if statement or a loop statement such as while or for loop, and I still only get 1 output. For example if I put my profit exit first it will only run that condition and if I switch to my loss it only does that condition, It is entering correct where it does enter on my break condition but other then that its incorrect, I dont know if I should have my exit stragety outside my if loop or if I need to write this another way. Here is the code:

Comment: I do know that "buy" was incorrect, its just left over code from changing it so many times. But this is general problem

Comment: THIS DOES WORK, BUT idk im wanting 2 seperate enties. 

strategy.ext("Exit - on Trade", "Short", profit = short_take_profit, loss = short_stop_loss)

But isnt there like a way where i can have 2 seperate enteries so its tracked better or em Im just stupid

Comment: Use one `strategy.exit` call with SL and TP together: `strategy.exit("Exit", "Short", loss=short_stop_loss, profit = short_take_profit)`. If you need "disable / endable" SL or TP, set `short_stop_loss := na` or `short_take_profit := na` accordingly.